# Is it possible to host Discourse in a Raspberry 3?

Tags: server

Some time ago someone asked if it was possible to host a Discourse forum (https://www.discourse.org/) in a Raspberry. The answer was no.
Now that a new model is out, I'll ask again. Is it possible now? Any clue about it?

Comment: this may be useful. http://blog.hypriot.com/post/heavily-armed-after-major-upgrade-raspberry-pi-with-docker-1-dot-5-0/